# How to add new line in email. (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I tried using the \n in the `message` variable but it had an error saying - unexpected character after line continuation character. what do I do?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

btn2.grid_forget()
nmt.grid_forget()
global ab
ab = nm.get()
nm.grid_forget()
ygt.grid_forget()
global ac
ac = yg.get()
yg.grid_forget()
clt.grid_forget()
global ad
ad = cl.get()
cl.grid_forget()
ctt.grid_forget()
global af
af = ct.get()
ct.grid_forget()


def send_email():
    global inval
    inval=TextArea.get("1.0","end-1c")
    btn4.place_forget()
    bully2.grid_forget()
    bully1.grid_forget()
    TextArea.place_forget()
    email = '********'
    password = '*********'
    send_to_email = '************'
    subject = 'Bully Report' 
    message = ab + \nac + ad + af + inval

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email
    msg['To'] = send_to_email
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
    server.quit()
    end()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't contain `\n`. Where did you try to add it? What does the resulting traceback look like? (Please [edit] your question to update it, rather than respond down here in the comments.)

Comment: Sprinkling your code with `global` variables is alarming. Don't do that.

Comment: The GUI code doesn't seem to play a role here, and is distracting. Please reduce this to a [mre].

Comment: ok, i edited it to include the \n

Comment: You only have to use `global` _inside_ a function to _write_ to a variable in the global score, not in the _global_ scope itself to make a variable readable in a function.

Comment: just a second..

Comment: You need to wrap `\n` with quotes. Try to replace the line this way `ab + '\n' + ac + ad + af + inval
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to include a newline character is `'\n'` with quotes around the string.

```
message = ab + '\n' + ac + ad + af + inval
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is supposed to be

message = ab + '\n' + ac + ad + af + inval

'\n' is a new line character and to be use as a separate string.